# What is the difference in RobertaTokenizer() and from_pretrained() way of initialising RobertaTokenizer?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am a newbie to **huggingface transformers** and facing the below issue in training a `RobertaForMaskedLM` LM from scratch:

First, I have trained and saved a `ByteLevelBPETokenizer` as follows:

```
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()
print('Saving tokenizer at:', training_file)
tokenizer.train(files=training_file, vocab_size=VOCAB_SIZE, min_frequency=2, 
special_tokens=["<s>","<pad>","</s>","<unk>","<mask>"])
tokenizer.save_model(tokenizer_mdl_dir)
```

Then, trained `RobertaForMaskedLM` using this tokenizer by creating a `RobertaTokenizer` as follows:

```
roberta_tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer(tokenizer_mdl + "/vocab.json", tokenizer_mdl + "/merges.txt")
```

But now, when I try to test the trained LM using a fill-mask pipeline,

```
fill_mask_pipeline = pipeline("fill-mask", model=roberta_model, tokenizer=roberta_tokenizer)
```

I got the below error:

> PipelineException: No mask_token () found on the input

So, I realized, the tokenizer that I have loaded, is tokenizing the `<mask>` token as well. But I couldn't understand why it is doing so. Please help me understand this.

After trying several things, I loaded the tokenizer differently,

```
roberta_tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_mdl)
```

And, now the `fill_mask_pipeline` runs without errors. So, what is the difference between loading a tokenizer using `RobertaTokenizer()` and using the `.from_pretrained()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare the property `unique_no_split_tokens`, you will see that this is initialized for the `from_pretrained` tokenizer but not for the other.

```py
#from_pretrained
t1.unique_no_split_tokens
['</s>', '<mask>', '<pad>', '<s>', '<unk>']

#__init__
t2.unique_no_split_tokens
[]
```

This property is filled by [_add_tokens()](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/00cc2d1df29f65a66e5fffbbb73b57822f3ecae1/src/transformers/tokenization_utils.py#L154) that is called by `from_pretrained` but not by `__init__`. I'm actually not sure if this is a bug or a feature. `from_pretrained` is the recommended method to initialize a tokenizer from a pretrained tokenizer and should therefore be used.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. That explains the difference between the two approaches. I'll wait for a few days before accepting this post to see if there is any better answer.